# Toggle button depending on snapshot value in react firebase app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm totally new in react environment, and I try to make an "add to favorite" web application. For that, i use firebase for my database and Algolia Search for search bar.

The principle is as follows: the admin user create item in admin area, and other user can see item in a section "catalog", and search for a specific item with the search bar powered by algolia service.

Now, I would like to implement an "add to favorite" function. For that, I created two functions "Add To Collection" and "Remove to collection", each connected to the button of their own. Everything work fine.

However, I would like that when the user adds an item to his collection, the button "add to the collection" disappears and that is the button "remove from the collection" that appears. So I created a function start with a let variable that evaluates to either "true" or "false", and my rendering is conditioned by the value of this variable. The problem is that I think I need to snapshot the keys of the items in the user's collection, and modify my let variable based on that. If the item is already in the user's collection, the variable indicates "true" and so it is my "remove" button that appears. And conversely, if the item is not in the collection of the user, the variable indicates "false" and it is the "add to the collection" button that appears.

I do not know if this is explicit enough.

Here is the part of my code that is concerned:

```
const Hit = ({hit}) =>{
  let itemExists = true;
  const userUid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
  const itemRef= firebase.database().ref(`users/${userUid}/collection`);

  //Logic for change the value of itemExist 

 if ( itemExists === false ) {
    return (
      <div className="item">
          <img src={hit.avatarURL} width={150} height={150}></img>
          <h1 className="marque">{hit.marque}</h1>
         <h3 className="numero">{hit.numero}</h3>
          <h4 className="reference">{hit.reference}</h4>
          <h4 className="marquesuite">{hit.marquesuite}</h4>
          <p className="cote">{hit.cote}</p>
          <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={() => removeToCollection(hit)}>Remove to collection</button>      
    </div>
    )} else  {
    return (
      <div className="item">
          <img src={hit.avatarURL} width={150} height={150}></img>
         <h1 className="marque">{hit.marque}</h1>
          <h3 className="numero">{hit.numero}</h3>
          <h4 className="reference">{hit.reference}</h4>
          <h4 className="marquesuite">{hit.marquesuite}</h4>
          <p className="cote">{hit.cote}</p>
          <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={() => addToCollection(hit)}>Add to collection</button>      
    </div>
    )
    }
  }
```

Comment: So what is the question exactly?

Comment: The question is : how to change the value (true or false) of itemExist ?

Comment: Since data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously, you'll want to store the `itemExists` value in the component's state and then use `this.state.itemExist` while rendering. That way, React will rerender the component when the data has loaded and you call `setState`. So something like: ``firebase.database().ref(`users/${userUid}/collection`).on('value', (snapshot) => { this.setState(snapshot.val()) });`` Look into React's `setState` documentation for more info.